# Edit database in management studio using visual studio c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ssms

I have created a database using SQL Server Management Studio and am now trying to edit that database using Visual Studio Express 2012.  I have connected the database to Visual Studio and can see my database but I have not been able to edit the database stored in Management Studio using Visual Studio.  I have created a form and am trying to insert what is entered into textbox1 into a specific cell on my database after the user defines the column name and row (using the primary key in my DB) with textbox2 and textbox3.  What code can I use to perform this action?  So far I have had no luck.  Thank you in advance for you help.

This is my current code:

```
      using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;



namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection myConnectionString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection()) // the "using" construct will close and dispose of the connection 
            {
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=Server ;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True");
                dbConnection.Open();
                maskedTextBox1.Clear();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

                String username = comboBox2.Text;
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table Name] (Column Name) VALUES ([Parm1])", dbConnection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Parm1", username);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
      }      


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Close the Window
            this.Close();
        }

        private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myConnectionString.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Sql is connected");
            myConnectionString.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add database columns dynamically? Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: This is my code so far to perform this task that has not worked.  I am not trying to add any additional rows or columns to my database but rather enter values into the cells of my database using pre set rows and columns.

Comment: You are confusing a db column with a parameter. See answer below:

Answer (score 0):

The VALUES clause should specify a parameter and that parameter should be specified when adding the parameter value. Try substituting the following:

```
String sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [Man Power] ([Person_Performing_Phase_2]) VALUES ([Parm1])";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Parm1", username);
```

**EDIT**

Your connection string is incorrectly formed. I believe the following format is appropriate for your current needs:

String myConnectionString =    Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

I would use the following code for inserting data, which opens and closes the connection for each operation. Note the "command.ExecuteNonQuery" statement - its omission is why your insert failed to work - although I am unsure why opening the connection did  not throw an error.

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection()) // the "using" construct will close and dispose of the connection 
            {
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                dbConnection.Open();
                maskedTextBox1.Clear();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0);
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

                String username = comboBox2.Text;
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Man Power] ([Person_Performing_Phase_2]) VALUES ([Parm1])", dbConnection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Parm1", username);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
      }
```

You should also remove all other _Click methods and replace the connection and command statement with the myConnectionString assignement.

Comment: Thank you for fixing that part, unfortunately using that code does not enter any data into my database in management studio.

Comment: I have amended my answer - see above.

Comment: I am getting the following error associated with the throw new Exception(ex.Message); line: 
“An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Performing'.”

Comment: I have updated my code in the original post.  I was unable to change my connection and command statements with myConnectionString assignments without getting errors.